# Probability of choosing one of two desired boxes out of five on the second try.

Tags: probability, statistics

I've got a problem that I'm not understanding how a given probability is being found.

If you have five boxes, three of which are empty and two of which have items you want, if you choose boxes in a random order, what is the probability that the second box you choose will contain one of the items you want (the first box you chose does not have one of the items, and the second box does)?

In looking at this problem, I'd say the probability of the first box you choose having one of the items is 2/5, since there are two out of the five with the items. For the second box, I'd say that given the first box was empty, this removes one empty box from the sample space, so we would now have a 2/4 = 1/2 probability of choosing the box with the item in it from the remaining boxes.

This means that given a random selection, the probability of the second box being the one with a desired item is (2/5)*(1/2) which is 1/5. However, the answer I am given is 3/10...and I cannot see how. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first probability is incorrect.  The probability of choosing an empty box on the first try is $\frac{3}{5}$; your $\frac{2}{5}$ is the probability of choosing a box that contains an item.

Your second probability is good: with only 4 boxes left and 2 that contain items you want, the probability of getting an item is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Mutliply them together, you get $\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{10}$.

Comment: *smacks forehead*....thanks! :D